# Better way of handling arbitrary contact info parameters

Tags: php, parsing, httprequest, string-parsing

I've got a form that contains contact info. Each has a type, and then the contact information itself. For example:

```
Type    | Contact
-------------------------------
cell    | 555-555-5555
home    | 444-444-4444
email   | abc@def.com
```

It's a functional requirement that users can add/remove contacts from the form using jQuery (showing only the contact info that exists - i.e. it's not a static contact form).

Since users can add/remove any row they like in the form, this produces HTTP parameters similar to the following (with numbers that are not sequential, and may not be contiguous):

```
contact_ty3=cell
contact3=555-555-5555

contact_ty994=home
contact994=444-444-4444

contact_ty45=email
contact45=abc@def.com
```

Therefore, numbers after the `contact` and `contact_ty` parameters are arbitrary, except that they serve the purpose to match up the type to the associated contact information.

So, on the receiving end, in PHP, how to I efficiently process the parameters, using the numbers to match up the types and contacts? I'm thinking the best way to do this would be via regex, but the simplest function I can think of iterates through the entire $_REQUEST array, strips out the parameters that start with `contact`, and go from there.

Is there a more efficient way? Seems like I'm writing a manual string/param parsing method, when perhaps there's a function to do this that I simply don't know about. Since I won't know the precise names of the form parameters beforehand, I can't rely on the assumption that there will be a `contact1`, `contact2`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some clever naming you can easily match them up on post:

```
<select name="contact[3][type]">...</select>
<input  name="contact[3][value]" ..>
<select name="contact[994][type]">...</select>
<input  name="contact[994][value]" ..>
<select name="contact[45][type]">...</select>
<input  name="contact[45][value]" ..>
```

And in PHP

```
<?php
    foreach($_POST['contact'] as $id => $data){
        echo "$id => type is {$data['type']}, value is {$data['value']}";
    }
```

Comment: Oh, essentially putting them in arrays. That's easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Iterating $_POST or $_GET is a good idea, not $_REQUEST as it might contain cookies. However, its best not to use regex. You can use substr for this purpose. Observe

```
foreach($_GET as $k=>$v) {
     if(strpos($Haystack, "contact") === 0) {
          //process $k
     }
}
```